# Why are "size mat" and "size(mat)" different?

Tags: matlab

I have these results:

```
>> size fives
1 5
>> size(fives)
4000 17
```

The latter is accurate. I'm not sure what the former is doing at all. When I type `size` with no args I get an error:

> Error using size
>    Not enough input arguments.

So I'm not sure why "fives" and "(fives)" both count as arguments but do different things.

Comment: [Command vs. Function Syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html).  Basically, your first form passes `fives` as a string literal (which has size `1x5`) while the second passes the variable.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Matlab, size without parenthesis gets the size of the literal string. For example, **size abcdefg** is **1 7** even if abcdefg is not a defined variable.